# Can Snaps or Flatpacks be installed from a local file?

Tags: software-installation, snap

I am having a Python App written and it will have to be installed locally. The programmer who works for me doesn't understand how to make a .deb file. He has tried many times and failed.

I am also a Xubuntu newbe but Snapcraft seems to really help create the package. I also have flatpack support

Question which of these two packaging methods will allow me to install the package from a download.

Comment: You should be aware that snap packages are rather crippled concerning their theming, since snap just supports a handful of themes. So in case someone doesn't use the default theme (like me) your app will have a different look and feel. What is the problem with creating a deb file?

Comment: Your programmer can get deb help at http://mentors.debian.net. Best practice is to distribute through a distro, for many reasons. Asking for free help from a distro that you don't intend to distribute through isn't very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Snaps and Flatpacks (and Debs and AppImages) can all be installed locally.

Choosing among them depends on more than current skills. Consider also the security patches you will need to promulgate, the support you will need to provide, and the future upgrades you intend to release.

Comment: This  is for a one time use application. The only person to use it will be me. It does one dedicated file mapping job. I need to know how to install a Snap from a local file.

Comment: Here's [an example](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/offline-snap-installers-and-possibility-to-update/275) of how to install snaps locally. If it's worth the effort to package properly, then it's likely worth the minor additional step of distributing properly.

Comment: How do I install a SNAP from a local file??

Comment: Read the thread that I linked to. How to install a snap from a local file is clearly explained.